# Rails - best place for helping code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, model

It is a best practices question. I have a model storing some parameters, used for generating a javascript file. One model instance generates one file. I use erb template for params substitution. Question is - where to place code that would generate js file after each model update? Model file doesn't look like a good option, since the model should not know about all the erb and file mess. Controllers are usually called in case of user request, which is not the case exactly. I've started looking at observers, but still in doubt.

Comment: Why exactly are you generating new JS file all the time? That sounds like an extremely bad practice to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the code to render the parameters to js code should be in a view. Views are for generating output.

Second, I would place the code to write to file in a controller. Controllers link models and views.
There has to be some event to generate the file. It might be the creation of an object, changes to the object or some explicit request to generate the file.
Each of these events schould be handled by the controller.

Observers are more to handle 'side effects'.

Answer (score 1):

Observers would be a good solution: start by running `rails generate observer jsfile` in your terminal. I'm using `jsfile` as your model name.

Edit your observer to your needs, something like

```
class JsfileObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
    observe :jsfile

    # after_save works both for update and create, which I guess is what you want
    def after_save(record)
        # generate the file with the params from your record
    end
end
```

Finally, don't forget to adjust your `config/application.rb`file

```
# Activate observers that should always be running.
config.active_record.observers = :jsfile_observer
```

And of course you'll have to restart your server ;)